Use of Green Theorem. Bermans Mathematical Analysis book
The excercise is:

Prove that the integral
$$
\int_L (yx^3+e^y)\,dx+(xy^3+xe^y-2y)\,dy
$$
is equal to zero, if $L$ is a closed curve, symmetrical with respect to the origin or to both coordinate axes.

The hint is:
Apply Greens formula to the doubly connected domain bounded by $L$ and any circle with centre at the origin and not intersecting contour $L$.
I did the math, and calculating the double integral over a circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$ of the integral
$$
\iint (y^3-x^3)\,dA
$$
gives zero as a result, what I do not understand is how to deduce the result from here. Maybe the original region can be mapped into a circle, or some sort of "sandwich" theorem.

I do not understand why the hint introduces the inner circle. What is the double integral over the region bounded by the curve, given the symmetries?
